# private method `test' called for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x7f2a8fb07c30>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there anyone can take a look. I got confused about this. Thank you very much.

```
[river@localhost demo04]$ rake db:migrate --trace
  WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateProducts: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:products)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

private method `test' called for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x7f2a8fb07c30>
./db/migrate//20120628020339_create_products.rb:5:in `up_without_benchmarks'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:104:in `create_table'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:445:in `create_table'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:346:in `send'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:346:in `method_missing'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:326:in `say_with_time'
/home/river/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:326:in `say_with_time'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:342:in `method_missing'
./db/migrate//20120628020339_create_products.rb:3:in `up_without_benchmarks'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:280:in `send'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:280:in `migrate'
/home/river/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:280:in `migrate'
(__DELEGATION__):2:in `__send__'
(__DELEGATION__):2:in `migrate'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:480:in `migrate'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:479:in `migrate'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `each'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `migrate'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:394:in `up'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `migrate'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:111
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/river/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/bin/rake:19
/home/river/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: How can anybody help you when you didn't provide any sources?

Comment: Please add the text from your migration file.

Answer (score 6):

I guess there is something wrong with your `20120628020339_create_products.rb` migration, you might be using a keyword there.

Comment: I have to say I'm an idiot. I miss typed the "text" to "test". I am very sorry. I'm a novice of ruby, so please forgive me. Next time I won't do that again. I am very sorry.

Comment: holy cow, I did the exact same thing... text!=test

Comment: Hah, I had the exact same problem. Thanks for posting your solution. :)

Answer (score 5):

I got this when I mistyped the datatype when I generated the resource. Instead of `content:text`, I typed `content:test`. Check your spelling.